# activerecord find through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I am trying to retrieve an activerecord object from my db. My models are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   has_many :domains, :through => :account    
end
```

And

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :domains
   has_many :users
end
```

And

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
end
```

Now I would like to retrieve a user based on the username and a domain name (lets assume that these are attributes of the User and the Domain classes respectively). i.e. something along the lines of

```
User.find(:first, :conditions =>{:username => "Paul", :domains => { :name => "pauls-domain"}})
```

I know that the above piece of code will not work since I do have to mention something about the *domains* table. Also, the association between users and domains is a one-to-many (which probably further complicates things).

Any ideas on how should this query be formed?

Comment: Are you sure your model associations are correct? They don't seem to be.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using Rails 3.x, the following code would get the query result:

```
User.where(:username => "Paul").includes(:domains).where("domains.name" => "paul-domain").limit(1)
```

To inspect what happen, you can append `.to_sql` to above code.

If you're using Rails 2.x, you'd better write the raw sql query.

Comment: I tried your approach but I could not get the correct join condition.  I ended up doing a combination which included a raw query and arel (yes it is Rails 3)

Comment: This is exactly what I was Google searching for. For manual reference, see: [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

**Note:** Make sure you pluralize the method name. The singular form will most likely call [Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include)

Answer (score 5):

The following piece of code did the trick:

```
User.joins(:account).joins('INNER JOIN "domains" ON "accounts"."id" = \
"domains"."account_id"').where(:users => {"username" => "Paul"}).
where(:domains => {"name" => "paul-domain"})
```

Sorry about the formatting of this long line of code