# Can't figure out how to update a model with new tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update my user Model with new tables, The tables being the following. 
I need the user to be able to choose a location upon signing up. 
I also need the users to be able to select up to 3 genres of music they'd prefer to listen to while signing up.

Now, The problem is I am going to let users select which genre they like, I also want them to be able to click on the genre link to see what other users on the website also enjoy that type of genre. So would that mean the genre would have to be a model while the location should be a table?

This is what I have in my user.rb,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :first_name, :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
    validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 10..100
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }, allow_nil:    true
    has_many :posts
    has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png", 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    def self.search(query)
      where("email like ?", "%#{query}%") 
    end
end
```

If you guys need any other code just let me know, And thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should take the time to review what, exactly, constitutes a [model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) in Ruby on Rails. *Every* database table is represented by a model file, meaning you have a users table and a User.rb model, as well as tables for location and genre with corresponding model files. You seem to have some very fundamental misunderstanding of the tools that Rails provides you, so it might be a good idea to review the basics before continuing with your project.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, would you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to ask for help the least you could do is clean up the spacing and indentation.  Group all of your validations together, etc.

As for how you want to setup your sign in process it looks like you're building your own.  Feel free to post all files related to your sign in process but it'd be a lot easier to use devise and customize it's views ([click for tutorial](http://www.peoplecancode.com/tutorials/adding-custom-fields-to-devise)).  You can have your users add their location & genre preferences here.

Before I go any further let's get on the same page for definitions.  I think you mean columns instead of tables in your question above but let me know if I misunderstood you.

Moving along:  you have a number of ways you can setup your genres.  I'd recommend creating a new genre table (not column) and associating that with your users through a 'through' table ([click for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594533/activerecord-find-through-association)) I know this link is old but it'll set you on the right direction.  This might be a lot for you to start with especially if you haven't done associations before but give it a try.

If all else fails you can reduce the number of features to start with and ask your users if they'd want that feature.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to make new Genre model with genres as table. When user want to select its location you can add has_one association when user only choose one location.

**genre.rb**

attributes: id, name, decription

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: genres_users
  has_many: users, through: genres_users
end
```

**genres_user.rb**

attributes: id, user_id, genre_id

```
class GenresUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

**user.rb**

attributes: your attribute field

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: genres_users
  has_many: genres, through: genres_users
  has_one: location
end
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

For details of [generating migration and association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update my user Model with new tables

[image]

As mentioned in other answers, each Model *should* represent a single table.

This is not always the case; [STI models](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) will not have tables, and you can use a model as you would a class (without DB integration).

However, the point is that you cannot just "add" tables to a model. You can add *associations*, which is a totally different concept. I'll explain it here:

---

**ORM**

To better understand what you're asking, it will help knowing that Rails is an [abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) for [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) & web server software. This means that when you deal with data, you're not pulling from a database, but dealing with *objects* which can be populated in various ways.

Rails is an MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller) framework:

[image]

This means that your "data" is not tied to tables etc, it's bound to *models* which are meant to provide you with objects that you can use within your application's *business logic*.

In other words, you shouldn't be thinking of your Rails app as a way to access *data*, but to manipulate *objects*.

This is done with the [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) called [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). ActiveRecord is the thing responsible for when you call the likes of `User.find`, and is behind the Rails' [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

What you're really asking is **"How do I add *associations* to my `User` model?"**

--

> I need the user to be able to choose a location upon signing up.
>
> I also need the users to be able to select up to 3 genres of music they'd prefer to listen to while signing up.

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | user | etc | location_id | created_at | updated_at
    belongs_to :location
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
    has_many :users
end

#app/models/genre.rb
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now, there is another answer which mentions having a model called `genre_user.rb`. This is for `has_many :through`, and I don't believe is applicable in this case.

I'd recommend using a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) join table, and simply validate the number of `genres` to 3 (I'll let you work that out):

[image]

To do this, you need a table called `genres_users` with the attributes `genre_id` and `user_id`. This will give you the ability to call:

```
$ @user = User.find 1
$ @user.genres #-> 1,2,6
```